# nested loop not working as intended powershell

Tags: powershell

Hello im creating a script that creates a history of interfaces ips but im having trouble with a nested loop.

```
for($r = 0; $r -lt $iface.Count; $r++){
    for($m = 0; $m -lt $iface.Count; $m++){
    if($ifaceold[$r] -match $iface[$m]){

    Write-Host "name true"  " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " "  $iface[$m]

        if($ifaceold[$r] -match $ifaceip[$m]){


        Write-Host "ip true" " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " " $iface[$m]  " "  $ifaceip[$m]

        }else{

        Write-Host "ip false"   " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " "  $iface[$m]  " "  $ifaceip[$m]

        }

    }else{

    Write-Host "name false"  " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " "  $iface[$m]

}
}
}

Result:
    name true   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 6
    ip false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 6   10.10.2.1
    name false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 5
    name false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 4
    name false   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 6
    name true   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 5
    ip true   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 5   10.10.1.1
    name false   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 4
    name false   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 6
    name false   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 5
    name true   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 4
    ip true   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 4   192.168.1.53
```

For some reason the second loop doesnt work as intended. Pretty much for example $iface will equal to Ethernet 6 and it will match $ifaces array that has Ethernet 6, Ethernet 4, Ethernet 5 as values. If $ifaceold matches with $iface then it will go to the next if sequence which is broken for me. I want to match now the Ethernet 6 ip with the $ifaceip values, and if they match then just get the output as true. But as you can see it matches the name 3 times but the ip only once for each interface. Can anyone point me to the right direction on why my second loop doesnt work?

Comment: Why are you iterating twice over the `$iface` array? Can you post some example of the content of `$iface` and `$ifaceold` and what you expect for output?

Comment: ifaceold = "Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5", "Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1", "Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53" 
and iface = "Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5", "Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1", "Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53"  for now as in if somebody changes ethernet6 to some other ip then it will be like 
iface = "Ethernet 6 10.15.10.1", "Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1", "Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53"  
as for the output i want to see it show if the ip is true/false for every value in $iface

Comment: Looking at where you're using ```$r``` and ```$m``` in your code, I'm assuming you first for loop should read ```for($r = 0; $r -lt $ifaceold.Count; $r++){``` - i.e. ```$ifaceold.Count``` instead of ```$iface.Count```?

Comment: @Marko4458 - PLEASE, put any added info _in your Original Post_, not buried in the comments. [*grin*]

Comment: first might be you're missing $ifaceold.count  in your first loop as @mclayton wrote, second you can try to remove parenthesis for your second  FOR loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i figured out what i had to do. the second loop had to be inside of the if case after it had matched the interface name and starts to compare the ip addresses

```
for($r = 0; $r -lt $iface.Count; $r++){
for($m = 0; $m -lt $iface.Count; $m++){    

    if($ifaceold[$r] -match $iface[$m]){

    Write-Host "name true"  " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " "  $iface[$m]
        for($q = 0; $q -lt $iface.Count; $q++){
        if($ifaceold[$r] -match $ifaceip[$q]){


        Write-Host "ip true" " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " = " $iface[$q]  " "  $ifaceip[$q]

        }else{

        Write-Host "ip false"   " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " = "  $iface[$q]  " "  $ifaceip[$q]
        }
        }
    }else{

    Write-Host "name false"  " "  $ifaceold[$r]  " = "  $iface[$m]

}
}
}
            Result: 
            name true   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   
            ip false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 6   10.10.2.1
            ip false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 5   10.10.1.1
            ip false   Ethernet 6 10.10.2.5   Ethernet 4   192.168.1.53
            name true   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   
            ip false   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 6   10.10.2.1
            ip true   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 5   10.10.1.1
            ip false   Ethernet 5 10.10.1.1   Ethernet 4   192.168.1.53
            name true   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   
            ip false   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 6   10.10.2.1
            ip false   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 5   10.10.1.1
            ip true   Ethernet 4 192.168.77.53   Ethernet 4   192.168.1.53
```